# How can I use MySQL statement 'show index' with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, pdo, show

I am trying to use PDO and prepared statements to get the primary key of a table. From other questions I saw that this is possible when executing something like this:

```
show index from TABLENAME where Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

The problem is that I can not use this from inside a prepared statement by using PDO under PHP. The code I use is the following:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;dbname=eclass', "user", "pass");
$stm = $pdo->prepare("show index from `TABLENAME` where `Key_name` = 'PRIMARY'");
$res = $stm->execute();
```

Now, the problem is that although the statement is created correctly, the execution fails. I am sure that this is not a permission's problem, since I run this as root with no result. When I directly run this SQL code from mysql prompt, it shows result indeed.

**EDIT**: It seems that after the weekend, the statement magically works. I don't know why this happened. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add `$<your_connection>->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened to catch errors.

Comment: Are you hardcoding `TABLENAME`?

Comment: `the execution fails` -- what is the error message?

Comment: Well today I tried it again, on the same environment, and the statement works as expected. I don't know why this happened. Sorry for bothering you! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure it fails? what is the result of this code?

```
$pdo = new PDO(
"mysql:dbname=" . SQL_DB . ";host=" . SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PWD,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
);

try {
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("show index from `TABLENAME` where `Key_name` = 'PRIMARY'");
    $res = $stm->execute();
    print_r($stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```